# Number of decimal places used in calculation? Or something else?

Tags: r

Sorry for the ambiguous title, perhaps a moderator can suggest a better one? Not really sure how to name the issue since I am not sure what the issue is. Lets simulate some data:

```
library(tidyverse)
n<-c(1:1000000)
bool<-1/n*n==1
head(bool,150)

[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [22]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [43]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [64]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [85]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[106]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[127]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[148]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Due to the fact that some results of division 1/n have infinite amount of digits, 1/n* 1 will not always come to exactly 1, but will be very close to 1. That is fine, that I understand. What I do not understand and what is surprising me is somehow arbitrary selection of numbers that do not come exactly to 1 as a result of 1/n* n

I played a bit more with these numbers and decided to plot falses.

```
num<-1:1000000
df<-cbind.data.frame(bool,num)%>% filter(bool==FALSE)
num2<-1:max(dim(df))
ggplot(dft2)+
  geom_point(aes(x=num2, y=num))
```

[image]

Can someone explain, what are these numbers and how are they different then other random numbers? Why is 1/49 * 49 not 1 and 1/53 * 53 is exactly 1? What are these bumps that I see on the graph?
I thought it might have something with the number of digits in repeating pattern of decimal digits that are used by R in divisions. I used scientific calculator with 100 decimal digits to try to confirm this.

Example:

1/7= 0.142857 142857 142857 142857  We can see a pattern, perhaps R decides that 0.142857 is precise enough just decides to round it?

*Because 1/7 * 7==1 is TRUE*

At the same time:

1/49= 0.020408163265306122448979591836734693877551 020408163265306122448979591836734693877551 ....

*1/49 * 49==1 is FALSE*

Here, the pattern of repeating digits is much larger, perhaps R never assess this pattern for long enough to realize it is in fact a pattern, but instead thinks it is a random set of numbers, much like with pi number?

I am aware that this is a site for scripting/programing questions and this question doesn't exactly fall into that category, but then again, question is about how basic R mechanics work.

Edit: to demonstrate further the weird part:

```
weird<-sprintf("%.54f",1/n*n)
head(weird,150)
[1] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  [3] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  [5] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  [7] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  [9] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [11] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [13] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [15] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [17] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [19] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [21] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [23] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [25] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [27] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [29] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [31] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [33] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [35] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [37] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [39] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [41] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [43] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [45] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [47] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [49] "0.999999999999999888977697537484345957636833190917968750" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [51] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [53] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [55] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [57] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [59] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [61] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [63] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [65] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [67] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [69] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [71] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [73] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [75] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [77] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [79] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [81] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [83] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [85] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [87] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [89] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [91] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [93] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [95] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
 [97] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "0.999999999999999888977697537484345957636833190917968750"
 [99] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[101] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[103] "0.999999999999999888977697537484345957636833190917968750" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[105] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[107] "0.999999999999999888977697537484345957636833190917968750" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[109] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[111] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[113] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[115] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[117] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[119] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[121] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[123] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[125] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[127] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[129] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[131] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[133] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[135] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[137] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[139] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[141] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[143] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[145] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[147] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[149] "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: Worth noting that R doesn't implement basic math operations, they rely on standard C implementations that conform to very well documented standards for precision. To my knowledge, almost all programming languages don't consider patterns of repeating digits in how they store numeric values (though I'm sure there are some oddball exceptions).

Comment: No computer uses decimal representation. they all use binary representation. For example 1/5 =0.2 is not a recurring number, but in binary notation, this is similar to 0.001100110011.... Everything lies with the mantissa of the binary representation. and has nothing to do with the number being recurring in decimal notation. If the  error is greater than 2^-16, then the two numbers wont be equal

Comment: The linked FAQ is very good reading on the topic, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) provides language-agnostic explanations and examples.

Comment: But the general takeaways are (a) this is a problem common to almost all computer languages, (b) you shouldn't expect exact equality between floating point numbers calculated/produced in different ways, even if mathematically they should be equal, (c) so there are alternatives to `==` available or easily code-able that test for equality within a certain tolerance, rather than exact equality.

Comment: To all, I am not expecting equality between floating point numbers, I fully expected most  inverses of n multiplied by n will not be equal to 1, yet most are! And the question is, why, and why only those?

Comment: You are looking at the decimal (base 10) representation of these numbers. That's not what a computer sees. Look at the binary (base 2) representation of the floating point numbers. You get a very different outlook on what repeating decimals look like in that representation.

Comment: You can look at the raw bytes with `split_n <- function(n) function(x) split(x, seq_along(x) %/% n); n <- 1:1000; writeBin(1/n*n, raw()) |> split_n(8)()` for example

Comment: I can't find the original blog post/code any more, but this is a nice semi-abstract representation of floating point error patterns from Danielle Navarro:  https://society6.com/product/floating-point-error_print